# Check if nw.js application is running on built version (prod) or development

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, node-webkit, nw.js

I am using [grunt](https://github.com/nwjs/grunt-nw-builder) to build my application, I want to use different configurations when the application is being run from built version and when I run it as a developer using simply nw.

Is there any such option which helps distinguish this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the desired configuration IN the processed source. There are many ways to accomplish this. Check out this blog post for some ideas http://addyosmani.com/blog/environment-specific-builds-with-grunt-gulp-or-broccoli/

Comment: Thanks, while I wasn't really aiming for this, but this does help. I will wait to see if I get any better solution.